# How to use a $lookup result on a $nin clause?

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have three collections: `users`, `questions` and `answers`. The `answers` collection contains the question_id and user_id. In the application level I need to find all users who fits in a query and not have answered a question yet. I was doing it building the query on application level with a $nin clause containing all the users ids who already have answered the question.

```py
already_answered = [
        ObjectId(a["user_id"])
        for a in db.answers.find({"question": question_id}, {"user_id": 1})
    ]
query = {
  ...
  "$nin": already_answered
}
users = db.users.find(query)
```

But, for questions who have many answers, the query document extrapolates the 16MB limit from MongoDB.

Then, I want to delegates this part of the query for the database level with `$lookup`.

```py
users = db.users.aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$match": query
        },
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "answers",
                "let": {"str_user_id": {"$toString": "$_id"}},
                "pipeline": [
                    {
                        "$match": {
                            "$expr": {
                                "$and": [
                                    {"$eq": ["$user", "$$str_user_id"]},
                                    {
                                        "$eq": [
                                            "$question_id",
                                            question_id,
                                        ]
                                    },
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                    }
                ],
                "as": "answered",
            }
        },
        {"$match": {"answered": {"$size": 0}}},
        {"$project": {"_id": 1}},
    ]
)
```

But this is horrendous slow. How can I achieve the expected result?

Comment: Please provide some sample data

Comment: What do you have on the questions collection?

Comment: @nimrodserok the question document contains only fields related to the question like question name, creation time and so on. All the three collections have a index on the _id field and the answers collection have a index on question_id and user_id

Comment: If this is the case `answers` collection you should use hush index on  `user` and on `question_id`

Comment: Thanks man! That's really improved the query speed! Do you think on another way I can get the same results with a different query?

Comment: Not with this structure, I would consider save the user ids on the question or vice-versa.